# AppleScript to extract email address from body of email and send auto response?

Tags: mail.app, applescript

Is there a way with AppleScript to extract a contact link in the body of an email and send an auto response with apple mail? (I'm running Yosemite)

I would like to auto respond to leads I receive from vendors and the customer contact information is in the body of the email.

Comment: Do you need to account for multiple links?

Comment: Yes, I do. Great point!

Comment: I have done this for several clients. It involves creating a rule to trigger the script, writing the regular expression to parse the message for an email address, and composing a new message with the extracted details.